# R Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : '"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions\gdalinfo"' not found

Tags: r, gdal, hdf

Lately I have been encountering many problems I have never seen before in R with geospatial packages, especially GDAL.

In particular I encounter this error (which when I had written the code I did not encounter):

`> sds <- gdalUtils::get_subdatasets("MCD43A1.A2020149.h18v04.006.2020161003923.hdf") Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :  '"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions\gdalinfo"' not found`

but in the directory the file gdalinfo does exist.

GDAL is installed in the machine via Osgeo4W. I tried to update it but still the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.